# Search the database to get date between

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server

I have this select statement:

```
SELECT *
FROM Room
LEFT JOIN booking ON (Room.RoomId = booking.RoomId)
WHERE booking.Roomid is null
  AND GETDATE() BETWEEN bookin.checkindate '" + TxtCheckIn.Text + "'
                AND booking.checkoutdate  '" + TxtCheckOut.Text + "'" + "
ORDER BY Room.RoomType
```

I want to check in the booking table if the date matches the checkin and checkout dates selected by users. If it doesn't match, the query should show all rooms in the room table (even if it is in the booking table), provided that they have different dates.

Comment: You are using `LEFT JOIN on booking WHERE booking.RoomID IS NULL` - effectively selecting only rooms with no booking. Then you try to search on the booking table? And it's not very clear what are you trying to achieve with that `BETWEEN`? Can you provide some sample data and expected results?

Comment: SELECT *
FROM Room
LEFT JOIN booking ON (Room.RoomId = booking.RoomId) GETDATE() BETWEEN bookin.checkindate '" + TxtCheckIn.Text + "'
                AND booking.checkoutdate  '" + TxtCheckOut.Text + "'" + "
ORDER BY Room.RoomType

Answer (score 0):

You need to determine whether any rows match the condition on the date.  To do this, the following query moves the date condition into the `on` clause.  Then it uses the window function `count()` to count the number of matches.  If there are none, then all rows are returned.  Otherwise, only matches are returned.

```
select t.*
from (SELECT *, count(booking.RoomId) over () as numMatches
      FROM Room LEFT JOIN
           booking
           ON Room.RoomId = booking.RoomId and
              GETDATE() BETWEEN booking.checkindate '" + TxtCheckIn.Text + "' and
                                booking.checkoutdate  '" + TxtCheckOut.Text + "'" + "
     ) t
where numMatches > 0 and RoomId is not null or numMatches = 0
ORDER BY Room.RoomType
```

Comment: I have tried it but i am having error 

Incorrect syntax near '07/25/2013'.

<pre lang="sql">Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Incorrect syntax near &#39;07/25/2013&#39;.</pre>


above is the error i get, thank, how do i resolve
thanks for your time, i really do appreciate

Comment: Try running the query first with hardcoded dates to see if it works.  That constant is not in the query, so it is the method that it is being passed in.